# Lagrangian multiplier problem

Tags: systems-of-equations, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have a function $f=x^3+xy^2$ and a constraint $xy=z^2$ where $z\in \mathbb R$ that I have to solve using Lagrangian multipliers. This is what I have done so far:

The Lagrangian function is as follows: $L(x,y,z)=x^3+xy^2+\lambda(xy-z^2)$

Calculating the first order derivatives and setting them equal to zero:

(1)$\quad\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=3x^2+y\lambda+y^2=0$

(2)$\quad\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=x(2y+\lambda)=0$

(3)$\quad\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}=-2z\lambda=0$

(4)$\quad\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}=xy-z^2=0$

Solving the system of equations:

$\quad$Using (2) I get that $x=0$.

$\quad$Using (4) I get $z=\sqrt{xy}$, which substituting $x=0$ is $z=\sqrt{0\times y}=0$, so $z=0$.

$\quad$Substituting $x=0$ and $z=0$ back into (4) I get that $y=0$.

$\quad$Shifting (2) around, I get that $\lambda=-2y$, and substituting in $y=0$ gets me $\lambda=0$.

So I get that $x=y=z=\lambda=0$.
This feels like a strange result to me, could anyone verify that this is correct?

Comment: (2) does not immediately give you $x=0$, but rather $x=0$ OR $2y+\lambda=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $z$ is a constant, so you don't care about the derivative with respect to $z$. Then:
$$3x^2+\lambda y+y^2=0\\x(2y+\lambda)=0\\xy=z^2$$
Let's discuss now the case $z=0$. From the 3rd equation it implies $y=0$ or $x=0$ (or both). If $y=0$, from the first equation you get $x=0$. If $x=0$ you get $y=-\lambda$. This makes sense, since $x=0$ implies $f(x,y)=0$, independent of $y$. So the minimum value of $f(x,y)$ is $0$ for $x=0$ and any $y$.

Now for $z\ne 0$, it means $x\ne 0$ and $y\ne 0$. Then, from the second equation $\lambda=-2y$. Plugging into the first equation you get $$3x^2-y^2=0$$Together with $xy=z^2$ you can now solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So the solution is either $x=0, y={\rm I\!R}$ or the solution of the system of equations $3x^2-y^2=0$ and $xy=z^2$?

Comment: Yes. The first solution is valid only when $z=0$.

Comment: Solving the second system of equations I got that $x=\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{3}}$ and $y=a\sqrt[4]{3}$.

Comment: Also note that for $z=0$, $x=0$ is not a minimum or a maximum. Take for example $y=0$. Then $f(x,0)=x^3$. You have the derivative of $f$ equal to $0$ at $0$, but that's not a minimum or maximum.

Comment: And you mean $z$ not $a$